# Is there a synonym for "manual entry"?

Tags: synonyms

Consider a comparison of selecting from a list versus directly entering an option. Would you call the latter "manual entry" or something else?

For example, are there alternatives in sentences like the following:

- To fill in this form, would you like people to select from a list or enter a value manually?
- You can choose between selecting from a list or manual entry for this value.

Some options I've considered:

- Direct entry
- Direct input

I'm trying to avoid references to "typing" because a person with a disability might not be able to type easily.

Comment: The opposite of selecting a value from a list is most frequently referred to as "manual entry" but I understand your doubt about its appropriateness because choosing from a list is not really "automatic entry". You could use the term "free form entry" which is the opposite of "constrained entry" which is what the drop down list actually is. However how many of your users would understand the term I don't really know.

Comment: A [previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161081/what-is-free-form-data-entry) in this forum raised the term **free-form entry**.

Comment: Personally, I don't like "manual" because selecting from a list is no less "manual" (and, if we're going to get literal, it also makes assumptions about physical abilities and input devices). I like "... select from a list or enter text"

Comment: *Choose one of the values from the drop-down list or **write** your choice into the text box*.  Yeah, sure, you can now quibble that people who use speech-to-text technology (and some other assistive technologies) might feel slighted but I expect that almost all of them (no evidence to cite) are well-used to the idea that *writing* is something which starts with thinking and ends with marks on paper (or its electronic forms) whatever happens in between.

Comment: With your first example sentence, you could alternatively say *"To fill in this form, would you like people to select from a list or enter a value **directly**"*